# Regular Expression for last few characters which are changing in every run

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner, neoload

I have a link like this :

http://URL:Port/bin/page1/spage1/content/sspage3/new/reallynew/2016/06/22/new-090132

The Portion after "/reallynew/" and /2016/, keeps changing at every run.

Is there a way via Regular Expression that , my scripts should work,  no matter whatever it is after "reallynew" and "2016".

Thanks appreciate your help.

Comment: how different is it when you say after the portion "/2016/" and after the portion "/reallynew/2016/".. don't they both imply the same or is the perspective different?

Answer (score 0):

Just correlate for what is between a LB of reallynew/ and the RB of quotation.  Substitute that in your script

```
http://URL:Port/bin/page1/spage1/content/sspage3/new/reallynew/{my_correlated_really_new}
```